# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Tags: java, hibernate

пытаюсь с помощью нативного запроса получить список данных из посгриса, но ругается на диалект, не догоню как сделать....

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

0 = {StackTraceElement@10265} "org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)"
1 = {StackTraceElement@10266} "org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)"
2 = {StackTraceElement@10267} "org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)"
3 = {StackTraceElement@10268} "org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)"
```

Сам код:

```
    public List attributes(String userName) {
    Session session = sessionProvider.getPublicSession();
    NativeQuery query =
            session.createNativeQuery(BaseObjectQueries.TEST);

    query.setParameter("userName", userName);
    return query.getResultList();
```

BaseObjectQueries:

```
String TEST = "select \n" +
        "\to.attr_id\n" +
        "from mgmt_object o\n" +
        "\twhere o.user_name = :userName";
```

Пробовал наследовать PostgreSQL95Dialect

```
          this.registerHibernateType(
            Types.OTHER, NativeQuery.class.getName()
    );
```

стало выбрасывать NPE, на этом я сдался....

Comment: а вы уверенны, что ваш запрос нативный, т.е. именно sql, а не  hql (вопрос риторический)?

Comment: У вас поля нигде не перепутаны местами (например версия диалекта и пароль)?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, запрос sql.Забыл добавить, что если с запроса получать count, тобишь получать одну строку, то все работает замечательно.

Comment: count отрабатывает, потому что проблема при чтении результирующей выборки, то есть проблема на этапе парсинга записей на уровне полей. И вот там, какое-то поле имеет тип, который хибер не может переварить... Посмотрите вот здесь:  https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/  Полагаю, используется небазовый тип данных постгреса, хибер про это не знает

Answer (score 0):

Сделал другим способом, переписал запрос на hql и вызвал через:

```
session.createQuery("тело запроса").setParameter("", object).list()
```

все заработало.